# How to finish the Activity from Custom Component?

Tags: android, custom-component

I want to finish the Activity from my custom component.
Question is how to get the reference  of the Activity from my custom component?
All I can get is `Context` in custom component.
I tried to convert `Context` to `Activity` (code is below), and it seems ok.
But I'm not sure about this. Perhaps there is a better way.
So, please tell me if this code is good enough or has any problem or risk.

```
public class MyCustomComponent extends RelativeLayout {
private Activity activity;
public MyCustomComponent(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context);     
    Button btn = new Button(context);
    btn.setText("finish");
    addView(btn);

    activity = (Activity)context; // here I want to get the Acitivity reference
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyCustomComponent.this.activity.finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

How about passing the activity to your component?

```
public MyCustomComponent(Context context, Activity activity, AttributeSet attars)
```

edit
You can add setActivity method to your class

```
public class MyCustomComponent extends RelativeLayout {
private Activity activity;

public void setActivity(Activity myActivity){
    activity = myActivity;
}

public MyCustomComponent(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    Button btn = new Button(context);
    btn.setText("finish");
    addView(btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            activity.finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

and in your main activity, add

```
    finishAction = (MyCustomComponent) findViewById(R.id.component);
    finishAction.setActivity(this);
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't very understand this. But I'm afraid the custom component can not work properly with constructor like this.

Comment: Hi, actually I just direct copy from your code and there is no problem to finish my activity.

Comment: That is not what I'm looking to. Thank you any way.